# c++ custom sorting a vector

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

Not going to go too deep into what I am doing because it is homework and I don't need it done for me but, I do need some help. I need to be able to specify what part of a `vector<vector<string>>` gets sorted first and under what parameters.

Currently what I am doing works perfectly by calling

```
sort ( v.begin(), v.end() );
```

If you write out my vectors they will look something like:

5 2 4 6 12 2 5

22 51 2 5 72 1

And I might need to sort it in descending order by the 2nd column and if the 2nd column is the same I would then sort by the next specified column.

called like ./sort 2,4

would sort by second column and then 4th.

I looked around and apart from writing my own sorting algorithm for this I don't know how I would customize the sort.

Comment: Why don't you pass a `std::vector<size_t>?`

Comment: Elaborate please. I am very new to c++ and must be missing out on something. Spent 5 hours today trying to get this program to do what it is supposed to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::sort()` has a second form that takes a compare functor as a third parameter. This lets you control the ordering of the sort without having to write the sort algorithm yourself.

The function you provide is given two objects, and must return `true` if the first object should be ordered before the second ("less than") and `false` otherwise.

E.g.:

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const vector<string>& v1, const vector<string>& v2) {
    // return true if v1 < v2, false otherwise
});
```

(Of course, it's up to you to work out the logic you need to get the sort ordered how you want it.)

Comment: This along the lines of what I am looking for, thanks. Is  there a standard way to specify the first string to check?

Comment: @TheUnknown: I'm not sure what you mean by that. In the code above you're sorting a vector of vectors. The sort function gives you two vectors at a time to compare. You would presumably need to iterate both vectors and apply whatever logic you need to determine how the two vectors should be relatively positioned.

Comment: Yes that makes sense I think I was jsut mistaken.